# Как правильно определить многострочные аргумент в angular/typescript?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular4

Здравствуйте у if есть два аргумента, как это должно выглядеть с точки зрения код стайла?  Допустим такой перенос на другую строку? Или это должна быть одна строка, но тогда она очень длинная выходит.  Или возможно эти аргументы стоит присвоить переменным и работать с ними? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
 private isTest() {
    if ((this.argSorce.nativeElement.clientWidth < this.maxWidthBlock) ||
      (this.argSorce.nativeElement.clientWidth < this.maxBlockContainer)) {
    } 
  }
```

Comment: this.argSorce.nativeElement.clientWidth я бы вынес в const все же, если этого будет достаточно то в 1 строку если нет то оставил бы так как есть.

Comment: Кстати внутренние скобки не нужны, у сравнения и так приоритет выше чем у "или".

Comment: Спасибо за ваши коменнтарии.  В целом ничего лучшего я не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочется читабельно, то должно быть примерно так:

```
  private isTest() {
    if (
      this.argSorce.nativeElement.clientWidth < this.maxWidthBlock ||
      this.argSorce.nativeElement.clientWidth < this.maxBlockContainer
    ) {
    }
  }
```